# How to pass a Javascript variable to Struts param tag?

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2

I tried to pass a Javascript variable to a struts param tag and I did it as follow:

```
 <script>
 var userName ="sample";
 </script>

 <body>
 <s:url action="myAction" id="myUrl">
 <s:param name="userName" value="%{userName}" />
 </s:url>
 </body>
```

But, it didn't work. Would somebody tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing two very different things :

- Struts runs in the server
- Javascript runs in the browser

And as Struts will first render the html page, and then the page - html and javascript - will be interpreted by the browser, they is no way to pass a javascript variable to a Struts param.

in `<s:param name="userName" value="%{userName}" />`, `userName` should be a `java bean`, server side.